# Interrupt jquery .load()

Tags: jquery, load, interrupt

This opens a div and displays the contents of the page loaded.
It works properly, but if you browse quickly over "test" links loads all the pages to the last.

any ideas for fix this?

trigger

```
<a name="1" class="zoom">test1</a>
<a name="2" class="zoom">test2</a>
<a name="3" class="zoom">test3</a>
<a name="4" class="zoom">test4</a>
```

jquery code:

```
$(".zoom").mouseover(function(){
    id=$(this).attr('name');
    page="../order.php";
    $('#trigga').load(page+'?id_ordine_testa='+id);
    $('#trigga').fadeIn();
}); 

$(".zoom").mouseout(function(){  
    $('#trigga').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Do you really need to make `id` and `page` global? If not, use `var id = ...` and `var page = ...` to make them local! Besides that, I think triggering AJAX calls when hovering a link immediately is a bad idea.in time.

Comment: you're right, but it was only to explain the problem. load ()  :)

Comment: @thiefmaster :this is for an intranet application, i don't care of responding time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin for jQuery:

```
$('.zoom').hoverIntent({
    timeout: 100,
    over: function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('name');
        var page = "../order.php";
        $('#trigga').load(page+'?id_ordine_testa='+id, function() {
            $('#trigga').fadeIn();
        });
    },
    out: function() {
        $('#trigga').fadeOut();
    }
});
```